# Is it good to start my career from the sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Myself Niranjan and i got one job as sharepoint developer. I am fresher. Also I doono sharepoint. They will give me training at the beginning but i have some knowledge on asp,net,ado.net,jquery etc. Now my the question is, 
Is it good to start my career from the sharepoint? Please suggest.

Comment: This question is off-topic. It is totally "your" call whether to start your career as SharePoint Developer. If you are interested then go ahead with it.

Answer (score 1):

it is not bad, SharePoint is hot product now a days. There are couple of areas which you consider for development, i.e building the apps, using the Client scripting. Now a days Majority of companies moving to Cloud, so Cloud development is good option.

Read this: http://www.matthewjbailey.com/a-career-in-sharepoint/